Import in a bicepparam file is not supported in the powershell module, but it is in the cli
I am using the import functionality in a bicep parameter file (bicepparam).
This works with the azure cli, but fails with the powershell module with the follow error:

Error BCP337: This declaration type is not valid for a Bicep
Parameters file. Specify a "using" or "param" declaration.

I am using Bicep CLI version 0.28.1, and version 12.0.0 of the Az powershell module.
I enable user defined funcitons with this bicepconfig.json file:
{
  "experimentalFeaturesEnabled": {
    "compileTimeImports": true,
    "userDefinedFunctions": true
  }
}

I add an export function in a cfg.bicep file:
@export()
func testFunction(x string) string => x

I import this in a test.bicepparam file
using 'test.bicep'
import * as vars from 'cfg.bicep'

param theVal = vars.testFunction('A Test String')

And this is my bicep file (test.bicep):
param theVal string
output Value string = theVal

I use this azure cli command:

az deployment group create --name 'aaaaa' --resource-group
MyResourceGroup --parameters $paramFile

This works, and I see the parameter named theVal has the correct string from the parameter file:

This fails when I use the powershell module with the same inputs.  Here is the command:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName MyresourceGroup -Name 'aaaaa' -TemplateParameterFile $paramFile   

I get the error at the beginning of this question: This declaration type is not valid for a Bicep Parameters file. Specify a "using" or "param" declaration.
UPDATE:
I've tried the solution Jahnavi and it's still not working. I get the same result.


The same bicep file which you shared is working with me in PowerShell as well. Can you try deploying it again. @Don Chambers

Instead of trying it with $paramFile, pass bicepparam file directly with -TemplateParameterFile parameter in the way
-TemplateParameterFile test.bicepparam without a $ symbol.
$in PowerShell or @ in CLI are not used when deploying a bicepparam file using bicep. If you are using JSON parameters file, then these will be needed for deploying and loading the contents of the file.
I have tried the same configuration as you did and was working for me with CLI & PowerShell as shown below.
test.bicepparam:
using 'test.bicep'
import * as vars from 'cfg.bicep'
param theVal = vars.testFunction('A Test String')

CLI:
az deployment group create --name 'xxxx' --resource-group xxx --parameters test.bicepparam


PowerShell:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName MyresourceGroup -Name 'xxxx' -TemplateParameterFile test.bicepparam



That's not working for me.  I'll update the original post, and add a screenshot.

Which version of the Azure PowerShell module do you have? I have 12.0.0.  Run this to see it: Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Az

Yes I also have the same version in my environment as shown. @DonChambers

I ran it on our deployment tool server, and it worked.  It's something with my box. I am checking everything now.
